# OpenCV: Quantifying the difference between two images quickly

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have two images and I want to get a sense for how much they differ on a pixel by pixel level. My basic idea was to take the two images, apply absdiff, and then go each pixel in the difference, take its norm, and store the norm in another array. The problem with this approach is that it is too slow for my application. Does anyone know any alternatives to this?

Many Thanks,

Hillary

The code for calculating the normed difference:

```
  uchar* row_pointer_image_difference;
  double* row_pointer_normed_difference;
  Vec3b bgrPixel;
  double pixel_distance;

  for (long int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
      row_pointer_image_difference = image_difference.ptr<uchar>(r);
      row_pointer_normed_difference = normed_difference.ptr<double>(r);
      for (long int c = 0; c < columns; c++){
           //calculate pixel distance
           bgrPixel = row_pointer_image_difference[c];
           pixel_distance = norm(bgrPixel);
           row_pointer_normed_difference[c] = pixel_distance;
      }
  }
```

Comment: How are you passing these arrays around? If you happen to be passing large arrays by value, you might consider passing by reference, which can be much faster (can't tell from your code). Otherwise, I don't see that you can avoid doing the pixel by pixel comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The arrays are getting passed around by reference.

Comment: You might then consider implementing something in OpenCL or CUDA, don't know if that is an option for you.  I don't see any obvious optimizations in the code that you posted.

Comment: Sounds good. I will take a look. Thanks for thinking about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clarify your use case better, in order to see what shortcuts are available. Ask yourself: What do you use the difference for? Can you live with an approximate difference? Do you only need to tell if the images are exactly equal?

Also, what computation time do you want to optimize? Worst case? Average? Can you live with a large variance in computation times?

For example, if you are only interested in testing for exact equality, early termination at the first difference is very fast, and will have low expected time if most images are different from each other.

If the fraction of duplicates is expected to be large, random pixel sampling may be a viable approach, and from the sample rate you can quantify the likelihood of false positives and negatives.